# How do I get around the limitation of having to place super constructor in the first line?

Tags: java, arrays, string, exception, getmessage

```
   public NoWheelsException(Car[] carArray){
        String holder = "";
        for (int i=0; i<carArray.length; i++) {
            if (i == carArray.length - 1) {
                holder = holder + carArray[i].name;
            }else{
                holder = holder + carArray[i].name + ", ";
            }
        }
        String message = holder + " has/have no wheels.";
        super(message);
    }
```

Written above is the ideal scenario that I'd have for my code, with the super constructor at the end. Although, since super has to be the first statement, I cannot figure out how to develop the string out of the array inline. I can't straight up use `.toString()` as there's certain criteria into what the string should look like. I've managed to figure out everything regarding Exceptions except this itty bitty detail. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

### Update

I got suggested to try Strin.join in order to link them together although unfortunately the object reference names differ from the name variable in the array objects...

Comment: Try moving the logic into some method(eg. `getHolder()`) that returns the message so your constructor can just have `super(getHolder());`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to create a private static method, since static methods exist irrespective of constructors and instantiation:

```
public NoWheelsException(Car[] carArray){
    super(buildMessageFrom(carArray));
}


private static String buildMessageFrom(Car[] cars) {
    StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();

    String separator = "";
    for (Car car : cars) {
        message.append(separator);
        message.append(car.name);
        separator = ", ";
    }

    return message.toString();
}
```

(When building a String in a loop, StringBuilder is much more efficient than string concatenation.  Each iteration of ‘holder = holder + …’ would create a new String object that eventually needs to be garbage collected.)

If you’re comfortable with Streams, you can do it all on one line:

```
public NoWheelsException(Car[] carArray){
    super(Arrays.stream(carArray).map(c -> c.name).collect(Collectors.joining(", ")));
}
```

Comment: Thank you so very much! This did it :) I had no idea that I can use private class methods inside of a super constructor, I assumed that there is no way to get subclass methods to work in a parent class environment.

Comment: It's not "inside of a super constructor". The argument is computed before the call is made.  `super(Foo())` is equivalent to `String tmp = Foo(); super(tmp)` except of course the latter cannot be legally written in that form.